# Formatting XML in Emacs

Tags: xml, emacs

I have a project with huge XML files that I'm copying and pasting into Emacs to edit.  It's all on a single line, so I'd like to have a tool to make one XML element per line.  Is there an Emacs function that I can use?  I guess I'll even settle for a command-line tool that nicely integrates with Emacs, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [xml-parse](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XmlParser#toc2) for years to reformat XML.  The specific command you want in that package is `xml-reformat-tags`.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

The feature you are looking for is typically called "pretty print". There is a pretty-print function for emacs at:

http://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/pretty-printing-xml-with-emacs-nxml-mode/

Also, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492/pretty-printing-xml-files-on-emacs) which has other options.

Comment: What could also be done is passing it through xmllint (part of the libxml2 package).

Comment: Do you happen to know what notepad++ uses? I am pretty sure it is a library and not a simple function.

Comment: Yes, "pretty print" was the term I needed to find that post.  However, it took about half a minute for nXml mode to "parse" my doc before it even started the indenting and other stuff.  Can I turn that off?  xml-mode works much faster for me.

Comment: nXml used to really choke on single-line XML files; one of the reasons I stopped using it by default years ago.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little Elisp function for that, that relies on xmllint from libxml:

```
(defun format-xml ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region 1 (point-max) "xmllint --format -" (current-buffer) t)
)
```